# for every frame $B$ with $k$ vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $B \cup v$ is a tight frame.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Prove the following: for every frame $B$ with $k$ vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $B \cup v$ is a tight frame. Is the same statement true in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Through the discussion provided in Frames for Undergraduates by Han, Kornelson, Larson, and Weber. I have seen and understand why for every frame $B$ with $k$ vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $B \cup v$ is a tight frame and when $k$ vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it does not.

Can someone help me formally write a proof for this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is a tight frame if and only if the frame operator 
$$
x\mapsto \sum_{j=1}^k \langle x,v_k\rangle v_k 
$$
is multiple of identity. Equivalently, the matrix $\sum_{j=1}^k (v_k\otimes v_k)$ is a scalar matrix.

Adding a vector $v$ to a frame means adding rank-1 operator $v\otimes v$ to the frame operator. Can this operation make the frame operator a multiple of identity?

In three dimensions, not always. Consider a frame with the frame operator
$$S=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$
If $S+v\otimes v$ is scalar, then $v\otimes v$ is diagonal, and being a rank 1 matrix, it must have just one nonzero value, namely $|v|^2$. Adding such a matrix to $S$ cannot make all diagonal entries equal.

In two dimensions, the following can be done: (i) choose an orthonormal basis in which the matrix of the frame operator is diagonal; (ii) increase the smaller diagonal entry by adding a diagonal rank-one matrix.